# Динамически забирать файл(бэкап) с папки

Tags: sql-server, резервное-копирование

В определенное время формируется бэкап базы. В названии файла хранится расширение, время, дата.

Есть процедура, которая забирает последний сформированный бэкап.
Хотелось бы узнать, каким образом с помощью входящего параметра я мог указать время, в которое был сформирован бэкап, и он его и забрал.

Comment: Ваш вопрос немного не в формате stackoverflow. Для начала покажите текст вашей процедуры или фрагмент кода. И объясните что вы пробовали сделать и что у вас не получается.

Answer (score 1):

Вот моя процедура.

```
USE testDB
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].get_file (@Dir varchar(600))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Directory TABLE ([subdirectory] varchar(256), [depth] int, [file] int)

DELETE FROM @Directory

INSERT INTO @Directory
EXECUTE master..xp_dirtree @Dir, 1, 1

DECLARE @top1datetime TABLE ([subdirectory] varchar(256),[extension] varchar(4),[time] varchar(6),[date] varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @top1datetime
SELECT [subdirectory],[extension],[time],[date]
FROM
(SELECT [subdirectory],
        --*************** Get Expansion File ***********************
        CASE WHEN RIGHT([subdirectory],3) = 'bak' 
        THEN RIGHT([subdirectory],3)
        ELSE 
        CASE WHEN RIGHT([subdirectory],4) = 'diff' 
        THEN RIGHT([subdirectory],4)
        END END AS [extension],
        --*************** get time from file title  ****************
        CASE WHEN RIGHT([subdirectory],3) = 'bak' 
        THEN SUBSTRING(RIGHT([subdirectory],29),12,6)
        ELSE 
        CASE WHEN RIGHT([subdirectory],4) = 'diff' 
        THEN SUBSTRING(RIGHT([subdirectory],30),12,6)
        END END AS [time],
        --*************** get date from filt title *****************
        CASE WHEN RIGHT([subdirectory],3) = 'bak' 
        THEN LEFT(RIGHT([subdirectory],29),10)
        ELSE 
        CASE WHEN RIGHT([subdirectory],4) = 'diff' 
        THEN LEFT(RIGHT([subdirectory],30),10)
        END END AS [date]
FROM @Directory) AS C
ORDER BY CAST (REPLACE ((CASE WHEN RIGHT([subdirectory],3) = 'bak' 
        THEN LEFT(RIGHT([subdirectory],29),10)
        ELSE 
        CASE WHEN RIGHT([subdirectory],4) = 'diff' 
        THEN LEFT(RIGHT([subdirectory],30),10)
        END END),'_','') AS date) DESC

--******************* Get last 'bak' file ***********************
DECLARE @bak_f varchar(200)

SET @bak_f=(SELECT TOP 1 [subdirectory]
            FROM @top1datetime
            WHERE [extension] = 'bak'
            ORDER BY CAST (REPLACE ((CASE WHEN RIGHT([subdirectory],3) = 'bak' 
        THEN LEFT(RIGHT([subdirectory],29),10)
        ELSE 
        CASE WHEN RIGHT([subdirectory],4) = 'diff' 
        THEN LEFT(RIGHT([subdirectory],30),10)
        END END),'_','') AS date) DESC)

DECLARE @bak_path varchar(600)
SET     @bak_path = @Dir+@bak_f

--*************** Get last file 'diff' **************************
DECLARE @diff_f varchar(200)

SET @diff_f=(SELECT TOP 1 [subdirectory] 
            FROM @top1datetime
            WHERE [extension] = 'diff'
            ORDER BY CAST (REPLACE ((CASE WHEN RIGHT([subdirectory],3) = 'bak' 
        THEN LEFT(RIGHT([subdirectory],29),10)
        ELSE 
        CASE WHEN RIGHT([subdirectory],4) = 'diff' 
        THEN LEFT(RIGHT([subdirectory],30),10)
        END END),'_','') AS date) DESC)

DECLARE @diff_path varchar(600)
SET     @diff_path = @Dir+@diff_f

IF OBJECT_ID('[testDB].[dbo].[tempFileBak]','U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [testDB].[dbo].[tempFileBak]

SELECT    @bak_path AS bak_path
        , @bak_f AS bak_f
        , @diff_path AS diff_path
        , @diff_f AS diff_f
        , (SELECT CAST(LEFT([date],4)+'-'+SUBSTRING([date],6,2)+'-'+RIGHT([date],2)+'T'+LEFT([time],2)+':'+SUBSTRING([time],3,2)+':'+RIGHT([time],2) as datetime)
FROM @top1datetime WHERE [subdirectory] = @bak_f) AS bak_t
        , (SELECT CAST(LEFT([date],4)+'-'+SUBSTRING([date],6,2)+'-'+RIGHT([date],2)+'T'+LEFT([time],2)+':'+SUBSTRING([time],3,2)+':'+RIGHT([time],2) as datetime)
FROM @top1datetime WHERE [subdirectory] = @diff_f) AS diff_t

INTO [testDB].[dbo].[tempFileBak]


END
```

> DeploymentTool_backup_2016_01_17_230003_0023014.diff
>   DeploymentTool_backup_2016_01_17_000102_3844565.bak

Вот название файлов бекапа